# C - print reversed file contents to stdout

Tags: c, string, file, pointers, reverse

I'd like to read the contents of a file and prints the reverse of its contents. Only using fopen, fgets, fputs, fclose. This is what I have done, however nothing is printed.

```
#include <sys/types.h>                                                          
#include <sys/stat.h>                                                           
#include <sys/fcntl.h>                                                          
#include <unistd.h>                                                             
#include <stdio.h>                                                              

int main(int argc, char *argv[])                                                
{                                                                               
    if (argc != 2)                                                              
    {                                                                           
        return 1;                                                               
    }                                                                           
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");                                              
    if (f == NULL)                                                              
    {                                                                           
        return 2;                                                               
    }                                                                           
    char buffer[4096];                                                          
    char reversed[4096];                                                        
    char *line = fgets(buffer, 50, f); //read 50 characters at a time                                   
    int length = 0;                                                             
    int j = 0;                                                                  
    while (line != NULL)        // while end of file not reached                                                 
    {                                                                           
        length = 0;                                                             
        j = 0;                                                                  
        for (char *temp = buffer; *temp != '\0'; temp++)    //find length of buffer                 
        {                                                                       
            length += 1;                                                        
        }                                                                       
        for (int i = length; i > 0; i--)          // reverse buffer                              
        {                                                                       
            reversed[j] = buffer[i];                                            
            j += 1;                                                             
        }                                                                       
        fputs(reversed, stdout);                                                
        line = fgets(buffer, 50, f);                                            
    }                                                                           
    fclose(f);                                                                  
    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

output:

```
(nothing)
```

example:

```
abcdef
ghi
```

expected output:

```
fedcba
ihg
```

Comment: Get length of string with `strlen` function. Start for loop from the back and loop until the beginning. Use `fputc` to output to stream.

Comment: Yes this is what I thought. But I am limited to `fgets` and `fputs`.

Comment: Is this an exercise intending to teach recursion?

Comment: It is an exercice to understand file manipulation in C

Answer (score 1):

You are starting at the wrong offset in

```
for (int i = length; i > 0; i--)          // reverse buffer
```

switch to

```
for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)    // reverse buffer
```

Otherwise you swap/reverse the NUL terminator and get an empty string

Comment: Oh yes, and I also did `i >= 0`. But now if I test it I get the last contents of the first line printed on the second and so on

Comment: Yes, you need to reverse also the lines, not only the contents of the line, I suggest to write the entire file in a buffer and then reverse this buffer at the very end.

Comment: Ok so I have filled the buffer with a while loop. I just cut/copy everything the loop except for `line = fgets(buffer, 50, f)` and put it outside. How can I reverse the lines. Also I directly get printed a new empty line when I run my program, and then the last line of the file.

Comment: I don't get you, If you have filled the buffer with the entire file contents, just reverse the buffer and the lines will be reversed too.

Comment: Yes, but only the last line gets reversed and printed. Managing new lines is quite tough

Comment: Are you resizing the buffer each time you read with `fgets`? it should work. `ftell` can help but it seems that you can not use it, in this case you need to resize your buffer (using `realloc` or a linked list ....)